# How to extract information from a tiff file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, contour

I have a tiff file that I loaded into ArcGIS. It has roads, rivers and other features including the 600m contour for the region. I want to create a file that only shows the 600m contour. How can I do that?

Comment: You seem to have a topographic map. It will not be trivial to filter just one contour line out of it. If you want to be ready soon just follow the contour and digitize manually a line on a new vector layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by user30184, the best method is probably manually your contour lines except if you have dozens of images.

For some automation with ArcGIS, you can try to reclassify your tif in order to isolate the contour (it it has a specific colour), then (if you have the licence) do our digitization with the help of [ArcScan](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000w00000001000000). If you don't have ArcScan but you do have spatial analyst, you can use the [Thin](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000003n000000.htm) tool on your reclassified tif, then convert it to lines using "[raster to polyline](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000009000000)"